# How would I write this regex pattern in lua with no libraries?

Tags: regex, lua

I would like to write this regular expression pattern:

```
(?<=bring a ).*?(?=,)
```

in lua but have no idea on how one would do so. If someone could point me in the right direction that'd be appreciated!

Regular expression pattern explanation: it's supposed to grab anything in between `bring a` and `,`

Comment: Have you tried using this pattern in your Lua code?  It already looks correct.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Lua patterns are very dissimilar to ordinary regexes. There's no way that would work.

Comment: @Joseph Maybe the lookarounds wouldn't work.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Nor would `.*?`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lua patterns aren't as advanced as regex, so you can't write a pattern that does exactly what the regex you posted does. However, you can write a pattern that does what this regex does:

```
bring a (.*?),
```

The difference being that you get the result you want in a subgroup, instead of as the whole match. Here's how you do that:

```
bring a (.-),
```

And you can use it like this:

```
str = 'I will bring a ball, so if you bring a bat, then we can have batting practice.'
for s in str:gmatch('bring a (.-),') do
    print(s)
end
```

That prints `ball` and `bat`.